# How can I suppress markers in KM plot?

Tags: plot, graph, google-maps-markers, stata

When I tried to use

`stcoxkm, by(exposure) msize(vtiny)`

after reading the Stata help documentation on markers, I get the following error:

> option msize() not allowed

The markers are basically taking over my entire plot and the graphical test for PH assumption is ineffective because I can't see the lines crossing over or running parallel to each other.

I have version 16.

Comment: Your problem can't be reproduced without a specification of data and we can't see a graph either. See the `stata` tag wiki for advice on reproducible examples.

Answer (score 1):

I think Stata manual and help file have many good examples for users to demonstrate their problems.

My understanding of your question looks like this:

```
webuse leukemia
stset weeks, failure(relapse) noshow
stcoxkm, by(treatment1)
```

This generated a graph:
[image]

Question is how to change or remove marker symbols. The following code may be something you want to start with:

```
stcoxkm, by(treatment1) obs1opts(recast(scatter) ms(i)) obs2opts(recast(scatter) ms(i)) pred1opts(ms(i)) pred2opts(ms(i))
```

I am using an evaluation copy of Stata 17.

[image]